# docker-compose equivalent for ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose

I'm in the process of deploying my flask application that runs on gunicorn and nginx. I'm able to get the app to run locally by creating a service for the flask app and another for nginx, and I'm able to run them using docker-compose.yml file. Now I know how to deploy a single service that I run using Dockerfile to ECS; however, I'm not sure how I would do the same for multiple services, so in others words, I want to know what is the ECS equivalent to running multiple services simultaneous using docker-compose.

I've tried having two containers when defining my task definition, but for reasons I'm unable to figure out the Tasks "fails to start".
Following is my docker-compose.yml file, to give you a better idea:

```
version: '3'

services:
  flask_app:
    container_name: flask_app
    restart: always
    build: ./flask_app
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    command: gunicorn -w 3 -b 0.0.0.0:8000 wsgi:server

  nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    restart: always
    build: ./nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - flask_app
```

Comment: "I've tried having two containers when defining my task definition, but for reasons I'm unable to figure out the Tasks "fails to start"." That is how you would do it. So if you are getting issues there you need to describe in more detail what you have tried and what your error is. You should include the ECS task definition JSON in your question. If the task fails to start there should be some logs in CloudWatch or a more detailed error in ECS.

Comment: See here for some examples: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/example_task_definitions.html#example_task_definition-containerdependency